# Laravel Horizon: Multiple instances on the same server interfering with one another

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, queue, laravel-horizon

I've got 3 Laravel apps all running on the same server that need use to Horizon.

I had a problem whereby the apps where clashing and jobs wouldn't be run.

After inspecting the Redis database using Medis I could see that there would be 3 entries for each job:

- PRODUCTION_horizon:2
- STAGING_horizon:2
- HRS_horizon:2

Where `production`, `staging` and `hrs` are my application names and `2` is the ID of the job.

If the job was dispatched from `staging` it may still be picked up by `production` or `hrs` and then just sit as pending for staging, never actually running.

After much searching i've found a work around for this by prefixing all of my queues with the app name.

So my config changed from this:

```
        'production' => [
            'default' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['default', 'emails', 'calculations'],
                'balance' => 'simple',
                'processes' => 10,
                'tries' => 1,
            ],
            'long_running' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['bulk_calculations', 'imports', 'build_parents'],
                'balance' => 'simple',
                'processes' => 1,
                'tries' => 3,
                'timeout' => 86400 // 1 day
            ]
        ],
        'staging' => [
            'default' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['default', 'emails', 'calculations'],
                'balance' => 'simple',
                'processes' => 10,
                'tries' => 1,
            ],
            'long_running' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['bulk_calculations', 'imports', 'build_parents'],
                'balance' => 'simple',
                'processes' => 1,
                'tries' => 3,
                'timeout' => 86400 // 1 day
            ]
        ],
        'hrs' => [
            'default' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['default', 'emails', 'calculations'],
                'balance' => 'simple',
                'processes' => 10,
                'tries' => 1,
            ],
            'long_running' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['bulk_calculations', 'imports', 'build_parents'],
                'balance' => 'simple',
                'processes' => 1,
                'tries' => 3,
                'timeout' => 86400 // 1 day
            ]
        ],
```

To this:

```
'production' => [
            env('APP_NAME') . '_default' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => [
                    env('APP_NAME') . '_default',
                    env('APP_NAME') . '_emails',
                    env('APP_NAME') . '_calculations'
                ],
                'balance' => 'simple',
                'processes' => 10,
                'tries' => 1,
            ],
            env('APP_NAME') . '_long_running' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => [
                    env('APP_NAME') . '_bulk_calculations',
                    env('APP_NAME') . '_imports',
                    env('APP_NAME') . '_build_parents'
                ],
                'balance' => 'simple',
                'processes' => 1,
                'tries' => 3,
                'timeout' => 86400 // 1 day
            ]
        ],
        'staging' => [
            env('APP_NAME') . '_default' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => [
                    env('APP_NAME') . '_default',
                    env('APP_NAME') . '_emails',
                    env('APP_NAME') . '_calculations'
                ],
                'balance' => 'simple',
                'processes' => 10,
                'tries' => 1,
            ],
            env('APP_NAME') . '_long_running' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => [
                    env('APP_NAME') . '_bulk_calculations',
                    env('APP_NAME') . '_imports',
                    env('APP_NAME') . '_build_parents'
                ],
                'balance' => 'simple',
                'processes' => 1,
                'tries' => 3,
                'timeout' => 86400 // 1 day
            ]
        ],
        'hrs' => [
            env('APP_NAME') . '_default' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => [
                    env('APP_NAME') . '_default',
                    env('APP_NAME') . '_emails',
                    env('APP_NAME') . '_calculations'
                ],
                'balance' => 'simple',
                'processes' => 10,
                'tries' => 1,
            ],
            env('APP_NAME') . '_long_running' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => [
                    env('APP_NAME') . '_bulk_calculations',
                    env('APP_NAME') . '_imports',
                    env('APP_NAME') . '_build_parents'
                ],
                'balance' => 'simple',
                'processes' => 1,
                'tries' => 3,
                'timeout' => 86400 // 1 day
            ]
        ],
```

This actually got it working! So essentially i've fixed it.

But this feels really wrong.

Now when I dispatch a job to a specific queue I have to do `MyJob::dispatch()->onQueue(config('app.name') . '_emails');`

Which is obviously not ideal.

I feel like there must be a better way but there's nothing in the docs explaining how to do this.

Is there a way to stop horizon interfering with each other? Maybe I should be using multiple Redis databases or something?

I realise that may seem odd posting a question of something i've already found a solution to, but I wanted to try and fix it myself before blindly asking and although I have found a solution, it really irks me that there is probably a much easier solution i'm just not aware of. Worst case scenario, if there isn't a better solution, someone else with this same problem will find this and discover my solution.

Comment: I think your best bet would be to specify 3 different redis connections to 3 different databases in your `config/database.php` and then pick one based on your `app.name` both in your `config/queue.php` (when specifying which redis connection the queue should use) and in your `config/horizon.php` (when specifying where Horizon should store his own meta info, the `'use'` key).

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is actually to use values for the REDIS DB in your .env file

```
REDIS_DB=2 (default is 0)
REDIS_CACHE_DB=3 (default is 1)
```

Redis by default has 16 databases, so assuming you have a max of 8 sites on the same server that should be fine.

I think you can use even more databases by adding extra entries to the `redis` section of `database.php`.

But i'm not sure what you would put in Horizon to use these.

One small tip if you're using https://github.com/luin/medis then you won't be able to see the other databases straight away you have to go to the terminal and use `select 3` to view the 3rd database.